# Indicate mute/unmute with i3status

Tags: audio, i3

Is there a way to indicate if the sound is set to mute or not using [`i3status`](http://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html)? I know how to show the volume (as explained in `man i3status`), but it doesn't distinguish between mute or just 0% volume.

Comment: Which version of i3 are you using?  It looks like sound support was implemented in [version 2.2](http://code.stapelberg.de/git/i3status/diff/src/print_volume.c?id=eb46963d4c88a75f1ac336275daf3d0d72a904ba). Are running a version of i3status older than that?

Answer (score 10):

Since version **2.8**, there's a `format_muted` string (see the [commit message and diff](http://code.stapelberg.de/git/i3status/commit/i3status.c?id=4bd0ba88c896d1ad9beba2eaadc01f1f2d172b5b)):

E.g.:

```
volume master {
   format = " %volume"
   format_muted = " %volume"
   device = "default"
   mixer = "Master"
   mixer_idx = 0
}
```

Here, in `format` I used [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io)'s icon [`fa-volume-up`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/volume-up/) and in `format_muted`, [`fa-volume-off`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/volume-off/).

Screenshots:

- muted:

  [image: muted]
- not muted:

  [image: not-muted]

Comment: How do you use FontAwesome for the icon but another font for the text?

Comment: I just load both fonts in `.i3/config` with `font pango: M+ 1m, FontAwesome, 10`

Comment: @henrique, can you please share your i3 config file? Thanks!

Comment: @zalman sure :) https://gist.github.com/hbpasti/39f2dd2d4dbd8fe04cbf

Comment: @henrique: The volume icons are just rendering as dots for me, but other icons are working fine (like the hdd icon). What could cause that to happen?

Comment: @skeggse, pango uses FontAwesome as a fallback font for glyphs missing from the main font; probably the font you're using already assigned something to the corresponding glyph in FontAwesome (e.g. U+F026). Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/i3#Iconic_fonts_in_the_status_bar

Comment: @henrique I figured that was the case. I set it to use `M+ 1m`, which I figured would work because that's what's in your config. Maybe I don't actually have the font installed.

Answer (score 9):

I am using i3sttatus version 2.7 (2013-02-27) and alsa under 3.10.6-gentoo x86_64 with default colors for i3status. If I set the volume to mute via amixer or alsamixer, then the volume indicator will be yellow, whereas manually lowering the volume to 0% retains the default white coloring.

Here is the relevant part of /etc/i3status.conf:

```
volume master {
format = "♪:%volume"
device = "default"
mixer = "Master"
mixer_idx = 0
}
```

Comment: I find it helpful to add a `format_muted` statement below `format`, like `format_muted = "%volume"`